# How can I display a 2D array of Tiles in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a tile based game where random tiles light up for a second and turn off. I created a 2D matrix of Tile objects and was wondering how I can render/display this 2D matrix. How can I use the Canvas and onDraw functions to do this? Or are there other rendering methods I can use? Thanks in advance for the help!

THE TILE CLASS:

```
public class Tile {
    String fileName;
    int symbolColor;
    int backgroundColor;
    boolean tested = false;         
    boolean seen = false;          
    int XxCor;
    int YyCor;

public Tile(int symbolColor, int backgroundColor, int x, int y) {
    this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    this.symbolColor = symbolColor;
    XxCor = x;
    YyCor = y;
}
```

The World class that houses the 2D grid of Tile Objects

```
public class World {

    private int width;          // Width & Height of the world
    private int height;

    public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private int FPxx = this.width / 2;         
    private int FPyy = this.height / 2;

    private int totalNumberOfTiles = width * height - 1;           
    private int TilesCounter;               

    private Random Pgenerator;      
    private Random Cgenerator;     

    private Tile[][] grid;
    public static final Tile NOTHING = new Tile(Color.BLACK,     Color.BLACK);       
private ArrayList<Tile> arrayOfMissedTiles = new ArrayList<>();        
private int missedTilesIndex = 0;     // Keeps track of the index No of the missed Tiles to re-display next
private int missedTilesInterval = 3;      // Number of Tiles to display before re-displaying a missed Tiles

/**
 *
 * @param width: width of the world grid
 * @param height: height of the world grid
 * @param seedP: seed for Peripheral points Random Generator
 * @param seedC: seed for Center points Random Generator
 */
public World(int width, int height, int seedP, int seedC) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    grid = new Tile[width][height];
    Pgenerator = new Random(seedP);
    Cgenerator = new Random(seedC);
}
```